# Installed Fonts Don't Display Properly In Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, fonts

I've installed several fonts on my computer and when I select them, they all give the same font which is not correct.

```
Order of the image below is Menlo, DejaVu Sans Mono, Fira Code
```

[To me they all looks the exact same, I should be able to notice the difference between them correct?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXg19.png)

Comment: The font size is excessively small, the em-size is only 6 pixels.  Fonts cannot distinguish themselves when they don't have any room.

Answer (score -3):

I met the same question.my partner told me that we should judge weather the letter exists or not in local font family at first.If exists then show it correctly,else 
change the font of all letters.